# Why is Rails discriminating against my route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rake

in my routes.rb file there's just two lines:

```
match 'movies/orderby/:field' => 'movies#orderby'
```

and

```
resources :movies
```

However, when I run `rake routes` on my project, I get a funny output, look:

```
              /movies/orderby/:field(.:format) {:controller=>"movies", :action=>"orderby"}
movies     GET    /movies(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"movies"}
           POST   /movies(.:format)                {:action=>"create",:controller=>"movies"}
new_movie  GET    /movies/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"movies"}
edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}
 movie     GET    /movies/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies"}
           PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"update",:controller=>"movies"}
           DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"movies"}
```

You see how the route I've hand-coded is different from the others? (it's the one at the top) Also, Rails **has not**  created a url helper for me....

I get the following error message all the time:

**undefined method `movies_orderby' for**

...Any ideas????

**EDIT:** the route **works** (i.e. if i type a matching URL, it get routed correctly) but I got **no** url helper method to put in my views!!

Comment: does it change if you change the order?

Comment: no. Rake now lists my route at the bottom, but again without the helper or the HTTP verb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define routes, the method `match` will not generate url helpers unless you specify what the name of the helpers should be. So I would recommend that you define it as following:

```
match 'movies/orderby/:field' => 'movies#orderby', :as => :movies_orderby
resources :movies
```

When you define the name of the route with `:as` then you will be able to use it in your views like this if you for example would like to order by `title`

```
<%= movies_orderby_path("title") %>
```

And as a side note, you had correctly defined the match route before the resources route. The other way around could have caused problems.

Comment: The [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) might be worth mentioning so that Felipe can help himself. And a `:via => :get` would get him the verb in the routes listing.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida: Sorry, I can't unask a question when there is no question, or can I?

Comment: If you're going to use `:via => :get` might as well just use `get` instead of `match`.